# Generator of multiplicative group of the finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Is it true that if the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ have the following realisation:

$$\mathbb{F}_q \simeq \mathbb{F_p[\alpha]}/(f(\alpha))$$

then $\alpha$ is the generator of its multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}^{\times}_q$ ?

I tried the following.
First note that $|\mathbb{F}^{\times}_q| = q - 1$, so if 
$$q - 1 = d_1^{e_1}\dots d_k^{e_k}$$
$\alpha$ is the generator $\iff$ $\forall i=1\dots k(\alpha^{d_i'} \neq 1 \mod f(\alpha)) $ where $d_i' = d_i^{e_i}$

But does there exist an example, where $(\alpha^{d_i'} = 1 \mod f(\alpha))$ for some $i \in \{1\dots k\}$ ?

Comment: If that were the case, then $F[\alpha]$ would have strictly smaller size than $q$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so we can say that $\alpha$ is always the generator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the first question:

> Is it true that if the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ have the following realisation:
>
> $$\mathbb{F}_q \simeq \mathbb{F_p[\alpha]}/(f(\alpha))$$
>
> then $\alpha$ is the generator of its multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}^{\times}_q$ ?

No. This is easiest to see in the particular case when $q = p^4$. In this case, each element of $\mathbb F_q \setminus \mathbb F_{p^2}$ generates the $\mathbb F_p$-algebra $\mathbb F_q$ (since otherwise, the $\mathbb F_p$-algebra it would generate would be a proper intermediate field between $\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathbb F_q$; but the only such intermediate field is $\mathbb F_{p^2}$), and thus qualifies as an $\alpha$. Hence, there are $q - p^2 = p^4 - p^2$ many possible $\alpha$s in $\mathbb F_q$. But the number of generators of $\mathbb F_q^\times$ is $\phi\left(q-1\right) = \phi\left(p^4-1\right)$, which is usually smaller than $p^4 - p^2$. (For example, if $p = 2$, then $\phi\left(p^4 - 1\right) = \phi\left(15\right) = 8$ is smaller than $p^4 - p^2 = 12$.)

I'm curious about the general case; is there an infinite family of $q$s for which every generator of the $\mathbb F_p$-algebra $\mathbb F_q$ is also a generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb F_q^\times$, or is this merely a small-number phenomenon?

Comment: But $\alpha$ generates $\mathbb{F}_{2^4} \simeq \mathbb{F}_2[\alpha] / (\alpha^4 + \alpha + 1)$, we can conclude it from the simple brute force. Or I just misunderstood you?

Comment: @envygrunt: I'm not sure I understand you well. $\alpha$ is not fixed in my answer; only the fields are fixed.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. I just wanted to find an explicit example for $q = p^4$. Your answer seems correct

Comment: What if we take $f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ as irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\alpha : f(\alpha) = 0$, so it's generates $\mathbb{F}_{16}$ and  $\text{ord} (\alpha) = 5$, looks like counterexample, isn't it ?

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible (haven't checked), then yes, it is a counterexample.

Comment: thank you for response

Comment: It is mostly a small number phenomenon, but can happen for relatively large fields. By [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), with a described set of exceptions, there even exists a prime $q$ such that $q\mid p^n-1$, but $q\nmid p^k-1$ for any $k<n$. Thus a root of unity of order $q$ generate the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ as an $\Bbb{F}_p$-algebra but not as a group. That is, unless $p^n-1=q$, when we are in the Mersenne prime case, and we have many counterexamples (but don't know if there will be infinitely many).

Comment: @envygrunt Correct, $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$ is a counterexample. A "smaller" one if $f(x)=x^2+1$ over $\Bbb{F}_3$. Its zeros are obviously roots of unity of order four, and reside in the quadratic extension $\Bbb{F}_9$, but won't generate it as a multiplicative group.

Comment: Anyway, when $p>2$, an element of order $p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+\cdots+p+1$ in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ will generate $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ as an algebra over $\Bbb{F}_p$, but won't generate the multiplicative group.